# App Engine Plugin for Eclipse Error : 400 Bad request, my mail is not valid

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, web-applications, deployment

I just want to deploy my Google Web Application to my App Engine and it goes wrong with this error:

> Unable to update app: Error posting to URL:
>   https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=expanded-metric-127214&version=2&
>   400 Bad Request Error when loading application configuration:Value
>   'hussein.wehbe.lopez@alumnos.upm.es' for ??? does not match expression
>   '^(?:(mail|mail_bounce|xmpp_message|xmpp_subscribe|xmpp_presence|xmpp_error|channel_presence|rest|warmup))$'

I have to explain that it was a project that I imported from a ZIP because I began it in another computer. The email `@alumnos.upm.es` is totally valid because it is a Google Account as well, and I had deployed other projects with it.

My Eclipse version is Luna and I'm correctly signed in with that Google Account. I just don't know what is happening